# How do I move bookmarks from operasync to visible toolbar?

Tags: synchronization, opera, bookmarks

Ok, title pretty much says it all, Opera sync did a pretty good job and backed up all my bookmarks before I uninstalled the old opera.

I can access all of bookmarks, passwords etc on the opera sync homepage : "https://www.sync.opera.com/bookmarks"

Now my problem is I need the old convenience of these being on the toolbar. How do I "move" these bookmarks from my sync history to my visible bookmarks toolbar so I can click on, see a dropdown menu and access it like old times ?

please tell me there is a way to do this, what's the point of syncing if I have to manually add them one by one to make it visible on the toolbar ?

Also, I JUST learned how to export your bookmarks to an html file and then re-import it after reinstalling, which I should have done before, but I was too late to google that. So is there any easy way to move them from sync to the accessible toolbar ? thank you for the replies in advance.

opera sync to work and move all my old to new bookmark toolbar

Comment: The question doesn't seem related to programming.